# Browser displays raw image data of jpeg. What headers should I make sure to have in the response?

Tags: java, servlets, browser, spring-mvc, http-headers

I seem to have run into an interesting problem where the browser happily displays an image generated by my Spring MVC web application as long as the URL to my controller is set as SRC of an IMG tag, but displays binary data when navigated directly to the URL.

My Spring MVC Controller generates some `BufferedImage` (thumbnail), converts it to `byte[]` and returns it directly into the response body using the `@ResponseBody` annotation on the controller method. I have registered a `org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter` message converter with the `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` and even set its `supportedMediaTypes` property to `image/jpeg`, which wasn't really helping, so I am setting the Content-Type header on the response manually in the controller method.

```
<img src="/images/thumbnail?id=1234" />
```

works fine and displays the image, however navigating directly to the SRC of the image (or right-clicking the image and choosing View Image) ends up displaying the raw data of the image.

Response headers, according to Firebug, received from a request to such URL (*http://localhost:8888/images/thumbnail?id=F0snPkvwhtDbl8eutbuq*) are:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Expires: Wed, 21 Dec 2011 12:39:07 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=2592000
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 6998
Server: Jetty(6.1.10)
```

One last word: in Firebug, clicking on the Response tab displays the image :-) What am I missing out? I thought the browser receives the content-type and content-length headers, knows to expect jpeg image, receives raw data for the jpeg, then displays jpeg in the empty browser tab. Somehow FF, and Chrome are displaying raw image data received.

Code I am using:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "thumbnail", method = { RequestMethod.GET })
@ResponseBody
public byte[] getImageThumbnail(@RequestParam("id") String documentId, HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        Document document = documentService.getDocumentById(documentId);
        InputStream imageInputStream = new FileInputStream(document.getUri());
        response.setContentType("image/jpeg");

        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(imageInputStream);
        ResampleOp resampleOp = new ResampleOp(THUMBNAIL_DIMENSION);
        BufferedImage thumbnail = resampleOp.filter(img, null);
        return getDataFromBufferedImage(thumbnail);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        return null; //return no data if document not found or whatever other issues are encountered
    }
}

private byte[] getDataFromBufferedImage(BufferedImage thumbnail) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        ImageIO.write(thumbnail, "jpg", baos);
        baos.flush();
        return baos.toByteArray();
    } finally {
        baos.close();
    }
}
```

**=== UPDATE ===**
I have followed @BalusC's advice and changed the url that produces the thumbnail to look like an actual .jpg file. This has made some difference in that now I can "Save image as" and the file name is no longer just "thumbnail" but ".jpg" which is good. However, both Chrome and FF (I have not even begun testing on IE) display raw JFIF data when loading the URL into a fresh tab/window. Still, image only displays if the URL is in the SRC attribute of an IMG tag and (thanks to browser caching) when user selects View image in new tab (but only if user does not refresh the tab, refreshing the tab will re-fetch the JPEG and display raw data in the window).

**EDIT**
I have just tested this in IE9 and this is the only browser where it works as expected. I can navigate to the URL directly and keep refreshing the page and I can see my controller being hit and the JPEG is loaded in the browser window. Excellent. Now to figure out what is wrong with the way FF/CR handle the JPEG I am sending.

**Additional info**
I am using Spring version 3.0.6.RELEASE
Running web app from Jetty

**EDIT**
I have solved my problem by **not** using `@ResponseBody` and `BytArrayHttpMessageConverter` - I tried the workaround proposed in another thread here on SO - that was to just write the bytes directly into the response output stream: `IOUtils.copy(imageInputStream, response.getOutputStream());` This is straightforward and works, I am still curious what was the weird problem with how the browsers would load the reponse in an `<img>` tag but not directly in a browser window. Anyone can shed more light on this, I would be really curious to find out more. I am leaving this question unanswered for now.

Comment: Could you place the return baos.toByteArray() after }?

Comment: ok, did that. didn't solve my problem but looks better now :-)

Comment: Still less likely, but ImageIO.write with "jpeg" i.o. "jpg" seems to be intended in the API. Should work both ways. Maybe different marker bytes.

Comment: What about <img src="http: / / localhost:8888/images/thumbnail..." ?

Comment: as i mentioned, the jpeg is displayed correctly, if and only if it is loaded into a `<img>` element by pointing the img `src` attribute to my controller.

Comment: Never seen this before on FF/Chrome. I'd expect exactly this kind of problem to occur on MSIE because it first identifies the content type of downloaded content based on URL instead of the response header. In any way, what happens if you add an extension to the URL mapping like `thumbnail.jpg`?

Comment: that's a good suggestion. Could you please repost this as an answer? This just might be the accepted one. Will try as soon as I get a chance

Comment: As per your update, well, the symptoms suggests that the `Content-Type` header is broken. Try to check the headers with Fiddler2.

Answer (score 2):

Try to update your annotation to:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "thumbnail", method = { RequestMethod.GET }, produces = {"image/jpeg"})    
@ResponseBody
```

Note `produces` attribute.

Hope that helps.

Comment: this could have been helpful if only the produces attribute of requestmapping was supported in the version of spring i am using. I'm using Spring 3.0.6.RELEASE This was added in 3.1 M2 Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: This doesn't explain the symptom that it works inside `<img>` but not inside a new tab/window.

Answer (score 1):

I just resolved my problem which is similar so maybe you (or someone else) can make use of it. I have icons stored in psql database:

```
create table images (image_id int not null primary key, data bytea)
```

My method in controller is:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = IMAGE + "/{imageId}", method = GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getImage(@PathVariable final Integer imageId) throws IOException {
    Image img = imageService.getImage(imageId);
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG);
    responseHeaders.set("Content-Disposition", "attachment");
    return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(img.getData(), responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

And since I'm using [thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/) my html looks like this:

```
<img src="#" th:src="@{${navigator.IMAGE} + '/-1'}" />
```

I put imageId = -1 in link just for testing. It works on FF.

Hope it helps someone :)